# Fill chart using final data

Tags: statistics

so all I know is that:
n=100.
i have 5 departments within the numbers: 0-1000.

md = 500.
avg =490.
lower decile=200.
upper quarter=600.

I really don't know how to use the formulas of each if I don't have any data.(fx,Fx etc)

[image]

**notice:** this chart is filled by the correct answers(2. 15 = box 2, the answer is 15), how to i get to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably $md$ is the median, so that tells you that $50$ are below that and $50$ are above.  The lower decile tells you that $10\%$ or $10$ are less than $200$, so that fills in one of your boxes directly.  The upper quarter being $600$ means that there are $25$ in the bottom two boxes together.  I don't think you have enough data to get all five boxes, but the mean being $490$ means there need to be a lot in the $200-400$ box to pull it down.

Given the answer, I think I can see how you are supposed to solve it.  I think it is a terrible problem and you should demand your money back.  Let the five numbers be $a,b,c,d,e$ in order.  The fact that $n=100$ tells you that $a+b+c+d+e=100$.  This is fine.  The fact that the median is $50$ is supposed to tell you that $a+b=d+e$, but there are many distributions with median of $50$ where this is not true.  To use the statement that the average is $490$, you are supposed to assume that all the ones in the $400-600$ box are at $500$, or at least that the set in the box averages to $500$, and likewise for the other boxes.  This is a reasonable way to approximate the average if this data is all you have, but you don't know it is right.  This gives you $(100a+300b+500c+700d+900e)/1000=490$  The lower decile of $200$ tells you $a=10$.  This is fine.  The upper quarter being $600$ tells you that $d+e=25$.  This is fine.  You now have five equations in five unknowns to solve.  Presumably the $F(x)$ column is the cumulative distribution, so each box sums the $f(x)$ boxes above and next to it.

Comment: so, I edited this chart using the correct answers. how do i get to box 2,3? because after that it can be easier to fill.

Comment: wow, thank you very much!
can you explain me why d+e=25? I didn't understand it.

Comment: Because you are told the upper quarter is $600$.  The contents of $d$ and $e$ together are all the things above $600$, so need to be one quarter of the total.